# Openbravo JSON REST get inactive registries

Tags: php, json, web-services, rest, openbravo

I'm consuming an OpenBravo JSON REST webservice through PHP and everything is working fine, but I can't receive data that has **"active"** field set to ***false***.

Is there any option I can submit to the ws in order to get inactive registries?

For example, this URL:

mydomain.com/openbravo/org.openbravo.service.json.jsonrest/PricingAdjustment?_where=active=false

returns:

```
{
  "response":
  {
    "data": [],
    "status": 0,
    "totalRows": 0,
    "startRow": 0,
    "endRow": -1
  }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: are u getting data without passing any filters?

Comment: No, I'm passing filter params. But the example url I posted is trying to retrieve all registries with "active" field set to false. By default, OpenBravo doesn't return inactive data, and I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: for that you have to write your own webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write custom REST service (as part of custom module) to get desired behavior

As openbravo core module adds few security constraints [you can have a look if you perform deeper debugging - issue may be due to client, organization access or any security related]

http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50:Developers_Guide/How_to_create_a_new_REST_webservice

Comment: As Mani Deep and Srinivas say, there's no solution but write my own REST service. Thankyou.